# Change color of button on toggle

Tags: android, android-button, android-drawable

I have an image button (star) which is used to mark something as favorite. I envision that when the user clicks on the star, the star will turn yellow. When they click on an already yellow start, it will go back to normal.

Transition from one color to the other would make a call to the server. I am doing that part already.

To change the color on click I did this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_fav" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_fav" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_ic_action_star" />
</selector>
```

However, this changes the color only for the time being when the buttons is clicked. It doesn't remain changed on the click, in other words, it doesn't toggle.

How can I toggle the color of a button on each click?

Comment: why you don't use toggle button ?

Comment: wow. I didn't know there was a toggle button..

Comment: take look on this tutorial
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-togglebutton-example/

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:state_selected` in the state list along with `View.setSelected(boolean selected)` in your Java code.